# Do I need to worry about concurrency when modifying a shared variable using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency

I've looked around SO but the usual answer is about I/O which is not my use case at the moment. I need to change stuff in memory.

Here's the code and then the question:

```
let counter = 0
let elems = new Array()
app.post('/counter', (req, res) => {
  if (counter % 2 === 0) {
    elems.push(counter)
  } else {
    elems.unshift(counter)
  }
  counter = counter + 1
  res.end(JSON.stringify(counter));
})
app.get('/counter', (req, res) => {
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ counter: counter, elems: elems }));
})
```

and this is the related `artillery` test:

```
config:
  target: 'http://localhost:3000'
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 40
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - post:
        url: "/counter"
```

I'm always getting the same result which is the following:

```
{"counter":2400,"elems":[2399,2397,2395,2393,2391,2389,2387,2385,2383,2381,2379,2377,2375,2373,2371,2369,2367,2365,2363,2361,2359,2357,2355,2353,2351,2349,2347,2345,2343,2341,2339,2337,2335,2333,2331,2329,2327,2325,2323,2321,2319,2317,2315,2313,2311,2309,2307,2305,2303,2301,2299,2297,2295,2293,2291,2289,2287,2285,2283,2281,2279,2277,2275,2273,2271,2269,2267,2265,2263,2261,2259,2257,2255,2253,2251,2249,2247,2245,2243,2241,2239,2237,2235,2233,2231,2229,2227,2225,2223,2221,2219,2217,2215,2213,2211,2209,2207,2205,2203,2201,2199,2197,2195,2193,2191,2189,2187,2185,2183,2181,2179,2177,2175,2173,2171,2169,2167,2165,2163,2161,2159,2157,2155,2153,2151,2149,2147,2145,2143,2141,2139,2137,2135,2133,2131,2129,2127,2125,2123,2121,2119,2117,2115,2113,2111,2109,2107,2105,2103,2101,2099,2097,2095,2093,2091,2089,2087,2085,2083,2081,2079,2077,2075,2073,2071,2069,2067,2065,2063,2061,2059,2057,2055,2053,2051,2049,2047,2045,2043,2041,2039,2037,2035,2033,2031,2029,2027,2025,2023,2021,2019,2017,2015,2013,2011,2009,2007,2005,2003,2001,1999,1997,1995,1993,1991,1989,1987,1985,1983,1981,1979,1977,1975,1973,1971,1969,1967,1965,1963,1961,1959,1957,1955,1953,1951,1949,1947,1945,1943,1941,1939,1937,1935,1933,1931,1929,1927,1925,1923,1921,1919,1917,1915,1913,1911,1909,1907,1905,1903,1901,1899,1897,1895,1893,1891,1889,1887,1885,1883,1881,1879,1877,1875,1873,1871,1869,1867,1865,1863,1861,1859,1857,1855,1853,1851,1849,1847,1845,1843,1841,1839,1837,1835,1833,1831,1829,1827,1825,1823,1821,1819,1817,1815,1813,1811,1809,1807,1805,1803,1801,1799,1797,1795,1793,1791,1789,1787,1785,1783,1781,1779,1777,1775,1773,1771,1769,1767,1765,1763,1761,1759,1757,1755,1753,1751,1749,1747,1745,1743,1741,1739,1737,1735,1733,1731,1729,1727,1725,1723,1721,1719,1717,1715,1713,1711,1709,1707,1705,1703,1701,1699,1697,1695,1693,1691,1689,1687,1685,1683,1681,1679,1677,1675,1673,1671,1669,1667,1665,1663,1661,1659,1657,1655,1653,1651,1649,1647,1645,1643,1641,1639,1637,1635,1633,1631,1629,1627,1625,1623,1621,1619,1617,1615,1613,1611,1609,1607,1605,1603,1601,1599,1597,1595,1593,1591,1589,1587,1585,1583,1581,1579,1577,1575,1573,1571,1569,1567,1565,1563,1561,1559,1557,1555,1553,1551,1549,1547,1545,1543,1541,1539,1537,1535,1533,1531,1529,1527,1525,1523,1521,1519,1517,1515,1513,1511,1509,1507,1505,1503,1501,1499,1497,1495,1493,1491,1489,1487,1485,1483,1481,1479,1477,1475,1473,1471,1469,1467,1465,1463,1461,1459,1457,1455,1453,1451,1449,1447,1445,1443,1441,1439,1437,1435,1433,1431,1429,1427,1425,1423,1421,1419,1417,1415,1413,1411,1409,1407,1405,1403,1401,1399,1397,1395,1393,1391,1389,1387,1385,1383,1381,1379,1377,1375,1373,1371,1369,1367,1365,1363,1361,1359,1357,1355,1353,1351,1349,1347,1345,1343,1341,1339,1337,1335,1333,1331,1329,1327,1325,1323,1321,1319,1317,1315,1313,1311,1309,1307,1305,1303,1301,1299,1297,1295,1293,1291,1289,1287,1285,1283,1281,1279,1277,1275,1273,1271,1269,1267,1265,1263,1261,1259,1257,1255,1253,1251,1249,1247,1245,1243,1241,1239,1237,1235,1233,1231,1229,1227,1225,1223,1221,1219,1217,1215,1213,1211,1209,1207,1205,1203,1201,1199,1197,1195,1193,1191,1189,1187,1185,1183,1181,1179,1177,1175,1173,1171,1169,1167,1165,1163,1161,1159,1157,1155,1153,1151,1149,1147,1145,1143,1141,1139,1137,1135,1133,1131,1129,1127,1125,1123,1121,1119,1117,1115,1113,1111,1109,1107,1105,1103,1101,1099,1097,1095,1093,1091,1089,1087,1085,1083,1081,1079,1077,1075,1073,1071,1069,1067,1065,1063,1061,1059,1057,1055,1053,1051,1049,1047,1045,1043,1041,1039,1037,1035,1033,1031,1029,1027,1025,1023,1021,1019,1017,1015,1013,1011,1009,1007,1005,1003,1001,999,997,995,993,991,989,987,985,983,981,979,977,975,973,971,969,967,965,963,961,959,957,955,953,951,949,947,945,943,941,939,937,935,933,931,929,927,925,923,921,919,917,915,913,911,909,907,905,903,901,899,897,895,893,891,889,887,885,883,881,879,877,875,873,871,869,867,865,863,861,859,857,855,853,851,849,847,845,843,841,839,837,835,833,831,829,827,825,823,821,819,817,815,813,811,809,807,805,803,801,799,797,795,793,791,789,787,785,783,781,779,777,775,773,771,769,767,765,763,761,759,757,755,753,751,749,747,745,743,741,739,737,735,733,731,729,727,725,723,721,719,717,715,713,711,709,707,705,703,701,699,697,695,693,691,689,687,685,683,681,679,677,675,673,671,669,667,665,663,661,659,657,655,653,651,649,647,645,643,641,639,637,635,633,631,629,627,625,623,621,619,617,615,613,611,609,607,605,603,601,599,597,595,593,591,589,587,585,583,581,579,577,575,573,571,569,567,565,563,561,559,557,555,553,551,549,547,545,543,541,539,537,535,533,531,529,527,525,523,521,519,517,515,513,511,509,507,505,503,501,499,497,495,493,491,489,487,485,483,481,479,477,475,473,471,469,467,465,463,461,459,457,455,453,451,449,447,445,443,441,439,437,435,433,431,429,427,425,423,421,419,417,415,413,411,409,407,405,403,401,399,397,395,393,391,389,387,385,383,381,379,377,375,373,371,369,367,365,363,361,359,357,355,353,351,349,347,345,343,341,339,337,335,333,331,329,327,325,323,321,319,317,315,313,311,309,307,305,303,301,299,297,295,293,291,289,287,285,283,281,279,277,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259,257,255,253,251,249,247,245,243,241,239,237,235,233,231,229,227,225,223,221,219,217,215,213,211,209,207,205,203,201,199,197,195,193,191,189,187,185,183,181,179,177,175,173,171,169,167,165,163,161,159,157,155,153,151,149,147,145,143,141,139,137,135,133,131,129,127,125,123,121,119,117,115,113,111,109,107,105,103,101,99,97,95,93,91,89,87,85,83,81,79,77,75,73,71,69,67,65,63,61,59,57,55,53,51,49,47,45,43,41,39,37,35,33,31,29,27,25,23,21,19,17,15,13,11,9,7,5,3,1,0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,118,120,122,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,180,182,184,186,188,190,192,194,196,198,200,202,204,206,208,210,212,214,216,218,220,222,224,226,228,230,232,234,236,238,240,242,244,246,248,250,252,254,256,258,260,262,264,266,268,270,272,274,276,278,280,282,284,286,288,290,292,294,296,298,300,302,304,306,308,310,312,314,316,318,320,322,324,326,328,330,332,334,336,338,340,342,344,346,348,350,352,354,356,358,360,362,364,366,368,370,372,374,376,378,380,382,384,386,388,390,392,394,396,398,400,402,404,406,408,410,412,414,416,418,420,422,424,426,428,430,432,434,436,438,440,442,444,446,448,450,452,454,456,458,460,462,464,466,468,470,472,474,476,478,480,482,484,486,488,490,492,494,496,498,500,502,504,506,508,510,512,514,516,518,520,522,524,526,528,530,532,534,536,538,540,542,544,546,548,550,552,554,556,558,560,562,564,566,568,570,572,574,576,578,580,582,584,586,588,590,592,594,596,598,600,602,604,606,608,610,612,614,616,618,620,622,624,626,628,630,632,634,636,638,640,642,644,646,648,650,652,654,656,658,660,662,664,666,668,670,672,674,676,678,680,682,684,686,688,690,692,694,696,698,700,702,704,706,708,710,712,714,716,718,720,722,724,726,728,730,732,734,736,738,740,742,744,746,748,750,752,754,756,758,760,762,764,766,768,770,772,774,776,778,780,782,784,786,788,790,792,794,796,798,800,802,804,806,808,810,812,814,816,818,820,822,824,826,828,830,832,834,836,838,840,842,844,846,848,850,852,854,856,858,860,862,864,866,868,870,872,874,876,878,880,882,884,886,888,890,892,894,896,898,900,902,904,906,908,910,912,914,916,918,920,922,924,926,928,930,932,934,936,938,940,942,944,946,948,950,952,954,956,958,960,962,964,966,968,970,972,974,976,978,980,982,984,986,988,990,992,994,996,998,1000,1002,1004,1006,1008,1010,1012,1014,1016,1018,1020,1022,1024,1026,1028,1030,1032,1034,1036,1038,1040,1042,1044,1046,1048,1050,1052,1054,1056,1058,1060,1062,1064,1066,1068,1070,1072,1074,1076,1078,1080,1082,1084,1086,1088,1090,1092,1094,1096,1098,1100,1102,1104,1106,1108,1110,1112,1114,1116,1118,1120,1122,1124,1126,1128,1130,1132,1134,1136,1138,1140,1142,1144,1146,1148,1150,1152,1154,1156,1158,1160,1162,1164,1166,1168,1170,1172,1174,1176,1178,1180,1182,1184,1186,1188,1190,1192,1194,1196,1198,1200,1202,1204,1206,1208,1210,1212,1214,1216,1218,1220,1222,1224,1226,1228,1230,1232,1234,1236,1238,1240,1242,1244,1246,1248,1250,1252,1254,1256,1258,1260,1262,1264,1266,1268,1270,1272,1274,1276,1278,1280,1282,1284,1286,1288,1290,1292,1294,1296,1298,1300,1302,1304,1306,1308,1310,1312,1314,1316,1318,1320,1322,1324,1326,1328,1330,1332,1334,1336,1338,1340,1342,1344,1346,1348,1350,1352,1354,1356,1358,1360,1362,1364,1366,1368,1370,1372,1374,1376,1378,1380,1382,1384,1386,1388,1390,1392,1394,1396,1398,1400,1402,1404,1406,1408,1410,1412,1414,1416,1418,1420,1422,1424,1426,1428,1430,1432,1434,1436,1438,1440,1442,1444,1446,1448,1450,1452,1454,1456,1458,1460,1462,1464,1466,1468,1470,1472,1474,1476,1478,1480,1482,1484,1486,1488,1490,1492,1494,1496,1498,1500,1502,1504,1506,1508,1510,1512,1514,1516,1518,1520,1522,1524,1526,1528,1530,1532,1534,1536,1538,1540,1542,1544,1546,1548,1550,1552,1554,1556,1558,1560,1562,1564,1566,1568,1570,1572,1574,1576,1578,1580,1582,1584,1586,1588,1590,1592,1594,1596,1598,1600,1602,1604,1606,1608,1610,1612,1614,1616,1618,1620,1622,1624,1626,1628,1630,1632,1634,1636,1638,1640,1642,1644,1646,1648,1650,1652,1654,1656,1658,1660,1662,1664,1666,1668,1670,1672,1674,1676,1678,1680,1682,1684,1686,1688,1690,1692,1694,1696,1698,1700,1702,1704,1706,1708,1710,1712,1714,1716,1718,1720,1722,1724,1726,1728,1730,1732,1734,1736,1738,1740,1742,1744,1746,1748,1750,1752,1754,1756,1758,1760,1762,1764,1766,1768,1770,1772,1774,1776,1778,1780,1782,1784,1786,1788,1790,1792,1794,1796,1798,1800,1802,1804,1806,1808,1810,1812,1814,1816,1818,1820,1822,1824,1826,1828,1830,1832,1834,1836,1838,1840,1842,1844,1846,1848,1850,1852,1854,1856,1858,1860,1862,1864,1866,1868,1870,1872,1874,1876,1878,1880,1882,1884,1886,1888,1890,1892,1894,1896,1898,1900,1902,1904,1906,1908,1910,1912,1914,1916,1918,1920,1922,1924,1926,1928,1930,1932,1934,1936,1938,1940,1942,1944,1946,1948,1950,1952,1954,1956,1958,1960,1962,1964,1966,1968,1970,1972,1974,1976,1978,1980,1982,1984,1986,1988,1990,1992,1994,1996,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020,2022,2024,2026,2028,2030,2032,2034,2036,2038,2040,2042,2044,2046,2048,2050,2052,2054,2056,2058,2060,2062,2064,2066,2068,2070,2072,2074,2076,2078,2080,2082,2084,2086,2088,2090,2092,2094,2096,2098,2100,2102,2104,2106,2108,2110,2112,2114,2116,2118,2120,2122,2124,2126,2128,2130,2132,2134,2136,2138,2140,2142,2144,2146,2148,2150,2152,2154,2156,2158,2160,2162,2164,2166,2168,2170,2172,2174,2176,2178,2180,2182,2184,2186,2188,2190,2192,2194,2196,2198,2200,2202,2204,2206,2208,2210,2212,2214,2216,2218,2220,2222,2224,2226,2228,2230,2232,2234,2236,2238,2240,2242,2244,2246,2248,2250,2252,2254,2256,2258,2260,2262,2264,2266,2268,2270,2272,2274,2276,2278,2280,2282,2284,2286,2288,2290,2292,2294,2296,2298,2300,2302,2304,2306,2308,2310,2312,2314,2316,2318,2320,2322,2324,2326,2328,2330,2332,2334,2336,2338,2340,2342,2344,2346,2348,2350,2352,2354,2356,2358,2360,2362,2364,2366,2368,2370,2372,2374,2376,2378,2380,2382,2384,2386,2388,2390,2392,2394,2396,2398]}
```

This result is what you should expect when no race condition takes place. So can I assume that if I need to change shared memory inside one single nodejs process then no lock is necessary? Because I was expecting that the line `counter = counter + 1` wasn't atomic but it seems it is.

Thanks

Comment: Do you aware that Node.js is single-threaded? I suppose this is explicitly related to your question

Comment: @Anatoly Is it that easy? Sure it's single threaded and I would say you must not worry about it. As long as you don't use any asynchronous operations the request should be processed within the main thread and shouldn't be queued in the event loop, therefore not processed by the underlying thread pool. But what about asynchronous functions sharing a global variable, any reason to worry about such scenarios?

Comment: What async functions do you have in mind? If it's about worker threads then they are not supposed to use shared variables at all.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that is single threaded. But I assumed each single HTTP call would be async in respect to the other.